Install horovod in torch 2.4
I tried to install horovod by using "pip install horovod" but it gives " note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for horovod
Running setup.py clean for horovod
Failed to build horovod
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (horovod)"  this msg. Any solutions for this?
I tried downgrade the torch version and install but  it didn't work.
